# moving around values around in a list using map plus function

Tags: python, list

I have a nested list that I want to do some data restructuring on. The nested list look like this:

```
[
 [1, 2, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 1, 0],
 [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 1, 0],
 [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 1, 1],
 [0, 1, 2, 1],
 [0, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 2, 1, 0, 0],
 [2, 2, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 2, 1],
 [1, 2, 4, 2],
 [0, 1, 2, 1]
]
```

I wrote a function to move that is supposed to either move the last element of the list to the front or add a 0 to the end of the list, depending on whether the length of the list is odd or even. This is the function I wrote:

```
def zero_move (list_obj):
  if len(list_obj) % 2 != 0:
    list_obj.insert(0, list_obj.pop())
  else:
    list_obj.append(0)
```

When I try to map the function to my nested lists it returns none values instead of new lists.

```
size_list = list(map(zero_move, sizes))

[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

This is my desired outcome:

```
[0, 1, 2, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 2, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 2, 1, 0]
[0, 2, 2, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 2, 1, 0]
[1, 2, 4, 2, 0]
[0, 1, 2, 1, 0]
```

I don't understand why I am getting `None` back instead of my desired outcome.

Comment: You are missing a  `return list_obj`, and functions without a `return` return `None` by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are not returning anything. Both the `insert` and the `append` operations are modifying the original nested lists in-place. If we inspected the value of the original list after the map:

```
>>> list(map(zero_move, sizes)
[None, None, ...]
>>> sizes
[[0, 1, 2, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0], ...]
```

However, since the operation we are performing modifies the original list, it is more idiomatic to use a for loop instead of `map`ping over the list:

```
for s in sizes:
    zero_move(s)
```

---

If however, you don't wish to modify the original list but rather return a new list reflecting the modifications, you will need to change your `zero_move` method to reflect that:

```py
def zero_move_return(list_obj):
  if len(list_obj) % 2 != 0:
    return [list_obj[-1]] + list_obj[:-1]
  else:
    return [0] + list_obj
```

Now, if you apply your map, you will get the result you originally expected:

```
>>> list(map(zero_move_return, sizes))
[[0, 1, 2, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0], ...]
```